# How to run command like "ipconfig" from my Angular5+ application?

Tags: javascript, npm, angular5, angular6

I have to execute some of CMD commands from my Angular application,
also tried shelljs but not working in my app.

Comment: The code that runs the cmd command has to be on the server-side. Angular would need to pass the string to the server, and it will execute the command.

Comment: can u please give me some reference for the same ?

Comment: Since you're using shelljs, use ExpressJS to create your web api, then let it pass the data between ShellJS and Angular. Search for "ExpressJS web api" for help

Comment: ok i will check. Thank you.